# How to inject html template and link controller to it while integrating as widget in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates

I am trying to create a widget which can be integrated in other websites as an external or third party widget. I am injecting html template which has been bootstrapped with angular into other sites.

Here is my sample website html which integrated my widget:

```
<html>
<head>    
    <script src="lib/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <button >Click</button> 
</div>  
<div id="example-widget-container">
 <!-- Widget Container,angular html template to be injected here -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the widget.js is used to inject html template into the widget container and its code goes like this:

```
var htm=
'<html>
<head>'+
'</head>'+
'<body >'+
'<div ng-app="myApp" id="ang" ng-controller="chatCnt">'+
    '<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="txt1" />'+
    '<button ng-click="click1(txt1,$event)">Click</button>'+
    '</div>'+ 
    '</body>'+
'</html>';

 var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
  script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  script_tag.setAttribute("src",'lib/controller1.js'); //Step 3-explained below
  (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);// injecting script
  $('#example-widget-container').html(htm); //appending html page in widget container
```

Now the issue is after i am injecting my controller file in the sample website(Step 3) and appending my html declared in variable 'htm' the template is displayed fine and controller file is loaded properly too, but the controller or any config function declared in my controller file are not invoked.Any variables declared in the controller file are not binded to the template injected.Is there something I am missing?I just want the controller to be linked to my template.Assume that angular libraries have been provided ,I haven't included them in the sample code.